# How can i select a row based on maximum value of a column by grouping it?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

[RAW TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUZH4.png)

I have a table that has records for orders in a daily basis as given above. What I want is selecting the row for each order_id which has maximum number of orders in a given month. So my final table will be as shown below.

[SQL OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu6e4.png)

Can anyone please help me? I appreciate in advance.

My table has millions of records, I could not find any solution so far. I am using Oracle SQL.

Comment: Please can you edit your question and share your simple data as text not images ? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4286884

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function:

```sql
SELECT "Date", Order_id, "#Orders", Truck_Name
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY Order_id, TRUNC("Date", 'MM')
           ORDER BY "#Orders" DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   tablo1 t
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

*Note: `Date` is a reserved word and you cannot use it as an unquoted identifier; best practice would be to use a different name but you could use quoted identifiers every time you want to refer to the column.*

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tablo1 ("Date", order_id, "#Orders", Truck_Name) AS
  Select  DATE '2021-01-01', 1,  800, 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2021-01-02', 1,  200, 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2021-01-03', 1,  400, 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2021-01-01', 2,  100, 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2021-01-02', 2,  500, 'E' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2021-01-03', 2,  700, 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2023-02-05', 1,  100, 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2023-02-09', 1,  200, 'H' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2023-02-15', 1,  300, 'J' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2023-02-05', 2, 1000, 'K' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2023-02-09', 2, 5000, 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  Select  DATE '2023-02-15', 2, 2500, 'M' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| Date | ORDER_ID | #Orders | TRUCK_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 800 | A |
| 2023-02-15 00:00:00 | 1 | 300 | J |
| 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 2 | 700 | F |
| 2023-02-09 00:00:00 | 2 | 5000 | L |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fhL4bTWG)

Comment: Thank you I will try it. What does r.* and m.* means here? As we don't specify the letters in the query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Baran I updated and fixed the answer. Regarding your question, they were meant to have been aliases for the table and in-line view used in the previous question.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. You are just great. Regards.